# Bash Script with AWK output to CSV

Tags: bash, shell, csv, awk, command-line-interface

I had amazing help on an AWK script [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/99610180?noredirect=1) and thought to myself it would be really cool to have the exact same output I am monitoring on the CLI to go to a CSV file. I **did** research and found a great answer [here](https://www.unix.com/unix-for-dummies-questions-and-answers/68844-generate-csv-file-using-awk-script.html), it basically showed code like this:

```
awk '{print $1","$2","$3","$4","$5}' < /tmp/file.txt > /tmp/file.csv
```

The first issue I have is /tmp/file.txt is not needed as my code is already producing the string with separated values. I don't know if my variables would work without running all new AWK commands, so I would prefer to just tag it to the end of the previous AWK command if possible. But I don't know how to implement the same concept within the actual script I am using. Could anyone show me the formatting schema I would need to tag this into the end of my script?

My ever-evolving script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
CURRENT_DATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
tail -fn0 /var/log/pi-star/MMDVM-"$CURRENT_DATE".log | gawk '
match($0, /received.*voice header from ([[:alnum:]]+) to ([[:alnum:]]+ 
[0-9]+)/, a) {
in_record = 1
call_sign = a[1]
channel = a[2]
}
in_record && match($0, /DMR ID: ([0-9]+)/, a) {
dmr_id = a[1]
}
in_record && match($0, /([0-9.]+) seconds, ([0-9]+)% packet loss, BER: 
([0-9.]+)%/, a) {
in_record = 0
print call_sign, channel, dmr_id, a[1], a[2], a[3]
}
' OFS=,
done
```

I still want to monitor via the terminal, I just think the appended output to CSV would be the icing on the cake. Am I overthinking it? Should it just be a separate script? If so, how?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for [tee](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tee.1.html)

Comment: TEE looks like a very powerful command! I will research it today for sure. Thank you.

Comment: I have tried inserting TEE again with schema issues. I put TEE between the TAIL and GAWK and it outputs the tailed document perfectly to a secondary file (including all the rubbish that GAWK removes), but I have tried placing the same TEE command after GAWK in many places and it just will not work, constant syntax errors. A shame because after reading on TEE it looks like the perfect solution. :/

Comment: wrt `constant syntax errors` - If you want help debugging syntax errors you should tell us what the error message are you're getting.

Comment: Answer updated. Sorry for not posting the exact errors, but thank you Ed.

Answer (score 1):

After posting the question with a better description on another thread someone responded with a correct answer. He said that basically what I was seeing is awk buffering output when it's going to a pipeline (since that's lower-overhead), but writing it immediately when it's going to a TTY. He went on to offer a solution by calling fflush() from the awk program.

"Call fflush(), after your print command, add an extra command fflush()."

That fixed it. Thank you all for your efforts.