# awk not printing output to secondary file, syntax error?

Tags: awk, scripting, command-line-interface

More with my radio logs... So far the work I have completed is great, push notifications are going out perfectly, too well in fact. I am getting bombarded with every accidental connection. I want to filter the log to only send notifications if the mic is keyed up longer than 1.5 seconds (the 4th field), cutting the notifications down to real communication only. I am trying to filter the original "completelog.txt" file over to the "filteredlog.txt" file. The original looks like this:

```
W7MIT,TG 91,4601149,0.5,0,0.00
W7MIT,TG 91,4601149,0.8,0,0.00
VA3GJB,TG 91,4601149,1.2,0,0.00
G0IOR,TG 91,2345614,11.6,0,0.00
G0IOR,TG 91,2345614,10.6,0,0.00
G4NHP,TG 91,2345614,6.2,2,0.00
GM0TKC,TG 91,2345614,0.5,0,0.00
EA8CTB,TG 91,2345614,2.3,0,0.00
EA8CTB,TG 91,2345614,1.6,0,0.00
GM1RCP,TG 91,2345614,0.5,12,0.00
```

The code I have tried using is here:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -v x=1.5 '$4 >= x' completelog.txt >> filteredlog.txt
```

Then I tried not appending (I think)

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -v x=1.5 '$4 >= x' completelog.txt > filteredlog.txt
```

Since neither worked I added sudo (don't think that is needed)

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo awk -v x=1.5 '$4 >= x' completelog.txt >> filteredlog.txt
```

And again not appending (still thinking that is what that means).

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo awk -v x=1.5 '$4 >= x' completelog.txt > filteredlog.txt
```

Then I just started guessing random things.

```
awk -v x=1.5 '$4 >= x'  completelog.txt
```

And again...

```
awk '$4>=1.5{print}' completelog.txt
```

All to no avail. I did get few permission errors even though the files are chmoded and even tried with sudo. Please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is happening when you try the various commands?  Do you get no output, unexpected output, an error message, ...?  Would you please edit your question to add some examples of what's going wrong?  Thank you!  **Edit** You may need to add `-F,` to your `awk` command line so that fields are comma-separated rather than space-separated.

Comment: Or simply `awk -F, '$4>=1.5' completelog.txt > filteredlog.txt`

Comment: If you're getting  syntax error as stated in your subject line then tell us what that error message is. Ditto for `I did get few permission errors` - tell us what specific error messages. Nothing in your question nor in the answer you accepted would explain/solve a syntax error.

Comment: I just remembered I gave you that advice in your previous question too - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56518422/bash-script-with-awk-output-to-csv#comment99624655_56518422. To be clear - any time you have an error message, include that message in your question so we can best help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you aren't setting the delimiter (Field Separator) in `awk` so it's expecting whitespace delimitation by default. Instead:

```
awk -F"," -v x=1.5 '$4 >= x' completelog.txt >> filteredlog.txt
```

You can also specify this in the `BEGIN` block of the `awk` script itself by setting the `FS` built-in variable:

```
awk -v x=1.5 'BEGIN{OFS=FS=","}$4>=x' completelog.txt >> filteredlog.txt
```

That sets the Field Separator `FS` and the Output Field Separator `OFS` to a comma.

Answer (score 2):

(not an answer, an extended comment)

The `sudo [command ...] > file` redirection is kind of misleading: you run the command with sudo privs, but the file redirection is done with *your* privs. This is because the shell processes redirections *before* processing the actual command.

Two workarounds:

1. use `tee` with `sudo` privs:

   ```
   some command with args | sudo tee -a privileged_file
   ```

   This runs the command as you, but appends to the file as sudo.
2. wrap everything in a shell with `sudo` privs:

   ```
   sudo sh -c 'some command with args >> privileged_file'
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Permission error noticed after posting, but the comma delimiter was also a great catch, thank you both.

```
pi-star@pi-star(rw):~$ awk -F"," '$4>=1.6{print}' completelog.txt > 
filteredlog.txt
-bash: filteredlog.txt: Permission denied
pi-star@pi-star(rw):~$ touch filteredlog.txt
touch: cannot touch ‘filteredlog.txt’: Permission denied
pi-star@pi-star(rw):~$ ls -l filteredlog.txt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 0 Jun 10 08:09 filteredlog.txt
pi-star@pi-star(rw):~$ sudo chmod 777 filteredlog.txt
pi-star@pi-star(rw):~$ ls -l filteredlog.txt
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jun 10 08:09 filteredlog.txt
pi-star@pi-star(rw):~$ awk -F"," '$4>=1.6{print}' completelog.txt > 
filteredlog.txt
pi-star@pi-star(rw):~$ tail -f -n2 filteredlog.txt
PD2RAL,TG 91,2042416,6.7,1,0.00
N1AJW,TG 91,2042416,2.2,2,6.70
```

Comment: Actually, no need for `{print}` -- that is the default operation if nothing else is specified.

Comment: Thank you, trying to learn it and I appreciate all the help I can get. There are some great tutorials that are so inspiring for many projects. But when it comes to seeking out help for AWK and SED both it is very difficult to find related content because everyone's use case is so specific and unique. Thanks again.

Comment: You could probably just go through the past answers from 'Ed Morton' or 'Charles Duffy' and earn a doctorate in `awk`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin thanks for the nod. Charles and I actually work together so you can imagine the code inspections :-). I typically defer to him on all things bash and he to me on all things awk.

Comment: @JaeNulton this isn't an answer, it's an important part of your question so add what you've posted here to your question and delete this "answer".

Comment: Thank you Ed and for your previous help as well. This is what is running in the bash script:
`sudo awk -F"," '$4>=1.8{print}' completelog.txt >> filteredlog.txt`
I have not yet removed the {print}, it seems to be working great, could it lead to error?

FYI, no matter what it might appear as, this is not for a commercial product. It is for some blind friends to have alternate access to the their radio logs from a system that has no accessibility features.